# How do I convert bytes to utf-8 without turning regular strings into NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, byte

I have a process that runs on multiple pandas dataframes. Sometimes the data comes in the form of bytes, such as:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame[['x']]
['x']
b'123'
b'111'
b'110'
```

And other times it comes in the form of regular integers

```
>>> pd.DataFrame[['x']]
['x']
80
123
491
```

I want to convert the bytes to unicode-8 and leave the regular integers untouched. Right now, I tried `pd.Dataframe['x'].str.decode('unicode-8')` and it works when the dataframe comes in the form of bytes, but it turns all the values to NaN when the dataframe comes in the form of integers.

I want the solution to be vectorized because speed is important. I can't use list comprehension, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function to first check before decoding. Something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Define the decode_if_bytes function
def decode_if_bytes(input_str):
    if isinstance(input_str, bytes):
        return input_str.decode('utf-8')
    return input_str
```

Decode df

```py
# Apply the function to the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[b'80',123,491]})
df['x'] = df['x'].apply(decode_if_bytes)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
x
0   80
1  123
2  491
```

Decode another df

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[b'123',b'111',b'110']})
df['x'] = df['x'].apply(decode_if_bytes)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
x
0  123
1  111
2  110
```

Comment: Is this going to be as fast as a vectorized function? I'm concerned that it has to check each row individually instead of applying to all values at once

Comment: Sure it does and will of course save you time because whenever you looking to decode a df you apply the function instead of having to write statements over and over again. You can give it a try to see if it works well for you. I edited the answer to include the output and you can take a look at it. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you've asked is to infer the dtype for the column and only attempt to convert it from bytes if it's non-numeric:

```py
if not pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(df['x'].infer_objects().dtypes):
    df['x'] = df['x'].str.decode('utf-8')
```

Test code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[b'123',b'111',b'110']})
print('','before',df,sep='\n')
if not pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(df['x'].infer_objects().dtypes):
    df['x'] = df['x'].str.decode('utf-8')
print('','after',df,sep='\n')

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[80,123,491]})
print('','before',df,sep='\n')
if not pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(df['x'].infer_objects().dtypes):
    df['x'] = df['x'].str.decode('utf-8')
print('','after',df,sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
before
        x
0  b'123'
1  b'111'
2  b'110'

after
     x
0  123
1  111
2  110

before
     x
0   80
1  123
2  491

after
     x
0   80
1  123
2  491
```

**UPDATE**: If the column is partially in bytes, such as x b'80' 123, this will work:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[b'80',123,491]})
print('','before',df,sep='\n')
df.x = np.where(df.x.astype(np.int64) == df.x, df.x.astype(str).str.encode('utf-8'), df.x)
df.x = df.x.str.decode('utf-8')
print('','after',df,sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
before
       x
0  b'80'
1    123
2    491

after
     x
0   80
1  123
2  491
```

Comment: This is great, I think this is the right answer. What if the column is partially in bytes, such as x b'80' 123?